# What is the delay method in Rails? What library is it coming from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I see this code:

```
Event.delay.create!(
  event_type: event_type,
  description: 'Automatically populated',
  date: Time.now.utc,
  eventable_id: subscription.id,
  eventable_type: subscription.class.name,
  app_context: app_context)
```

And this is the associated test:

```
  it 'logs events' do
    expect(Event).to receive(:delay).and_call_original
    subject
  end
```

What is the and_call_original method? What is the delay method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The :delay method is probably from Delayed Job, a queueing framework:

[Delayed Job Github Site](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/)

'and_call_original' is a delegator in the rspec framework.

[From rspec mocks](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/commit/2ab27764bdcadac77534e5a9a5937c3d3bece422)

Comment: Sidekiq [can also provide the `delay` method](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-extensions)